# How can black holes evaporate into photons if they contain no anti-matter?

Tags: particle-physics, black-holes, hawking-radiation, qft-in-curved-spacetime

Hawking theorized the evaporation of black holes. Photons are pictured to slowly radiate their mass away. The higher the mass the longer it takes (due to smaller tidal forces).

Which makes one question, how can the inside matter, composed of normal matter (so no anti-matter), be transformed into photons only? Doesn't this contradict all conservation laws in particle physics? Are there reactions in particle physics that transform all involved particles into photons, except matter anti-matter reactions?

Put differently, how can quarks and electrons annihilate? They both posses the same amount of plus and minus charge, but I'm not aware of processes in which they are destroyed, mutually or separately. Not even by the negative energy wave falling in from the horizon, which destroys mass but not the charges.

Most black holes form from stellar matter, excluding neutrinos, or collapsing neutron stars, containing up and down quarks only (in the ratio 1:2). If we consider the neutron black hole, you would think that their masses and charges can only be annihilated by negative energy anti up and down quarks. But what happens to the negative energy up and down quarks?

To put it differently one last time. Say we have a hole made up out of equal amounts electrons, protons, neutrons, and neutrinos, the same particles present shortly after the big bang. If the hole is evaporated, are they gone? If so, does that mean that particles can be annihilated without their anti-matter counterpart?

Comment: See the information paradox.

Comment: Nothing escapes from inside the event horizon. Hawking radiation is emitted from *outside* the event horizon. Nothing inside the horizon can affect anything outside the horizon. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/252236/123208

Comment: @PM2Ring Hey, there you are again! But where will all matter be gone after evaporation? How can matter, without antimatter, disappear from the scene?

Comment: @MrQ Is that about matter-antimatter? I don't understand how negative energy solutions can annihilate quarks and leptons or whatever particles inside.

Comment: Why should you need antimatter to make photons? Hawking radiation isn't due to annihilation; it's related to the Unruh effect.

Comment: @J.G. i just don't understand how a space containing particles (so no anti particles) doesn't contain them anymore after the evaporation.

Comment: I suppose it comes down to whether black holes conserve baryon number, lepton number etc., which [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-hair_theorem#Example) says they don't, while admitting that claim needs a citation.

Comment: @J.G.Hmmm... The link says: "Suppose two black holes have the same masses, electrical charges, and angular momenta, but the first black hole was made by collapsing ordinary matter whereas the second was made out of antimatter; nevertheless, then the conjecture states they will be completely indistinguishable to an observer outside the event horizon". But if one is positively charged, won't the other be negatively charged? So you *can* distinguish?

Comment: @J.G.Of course you can't differentiate a black hole from an antimatter hole. But you could before. What if two collide?

Comment: The Black hole was made from ordinary matter, but the vacuum outside the event horizon is undergoing spontaneous creation and annihilation of particles. When you try to probe the black hole with some weak matterfield (like scalar, electromagnetic field etc)in it's vacuum state, we see that the outgoing matterfield is no longer in it's vacuum state. The interpretation is that the BH is releasing energy which is absorbed by the matterfield in the scattering process.

Comment: @Felicia see the answer by user566 here https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7290/

Comment: @J.G. "Why should you need antimatter to make photons?" Photons are created on the horizon too, from the virtual part of the photon field. Their negative energy contributions don't have influence though on electrons that are part of the inside. That's what negative positron solutions can do only. Are only negative energy positrons falling in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## We do not know

We have never seen a black hole up close.  The black holes we are reasonably certain exist, are very far away.

Hawking radiation is a theoretical feature of very small black holes. The black holes we think we have seen are very big.  Their Hawking radiation levels would be undetectable, even if we were up close.

Meanwhile, we have theories.  The problem is that we have many such theories and they do not fit together.  In particular, general relativity and quantum mechanics aren't on speaking terms at all.

General relativity is our best theory for strong gravity.  Quantum mechanics is our best theory for elemental particle behavior.  Both are important to black holes and Hawking radiation.

As long as we do not have a working theory uniting the two, we cannot say we understand black holes at all.  Anything we say are educated guesses at best.

The following guesses doesn't fit together:

1. Black holes radiate, and will eventually lose all their mass to radiation.
2. This radiation does not reflect the particles used to make the black hole.
3. The total number of baryons and leptons are conserved.

As you are saying, these guesses can't all be true simultaneously.

[picop's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/696327/84855) states that some people believe number 3 is wrong, baryon and lepton conservation might not be absolute.

My personal less educated guess is that number 2 is wrong, Hawking radiation *will* reflect the particles used to create it. Everything is conserved. My reasoning is from the viewpoint of any in-falling particle, the black hole will evaporate before the particle reaches the singularity --- meaning the singularity will never form in the first place.

Another alternative is the "baby universe" theory.  Here the mass collected by a black hole will blow up as a Big Bang in a new universe.  One could argue that the baryons and leptons lost to our universe are conserved in the new universe.

Comment: Here are two difficulties for making your guess work. (1) Assuming we can trust general relativity outside the event horizon, no one outside the black hole can measure the baryon or lepton number of a black hole, by the no-hair theorem. Quantum gravity would need to hide a lot of information inside the BH. (2) In GR, matter crossing the event horizon of a solar mass black hole will hit the singularity in order microseconds, while the timescale to evaporate is much larger than the current age of the Universe. It is a big ask for a theory of quantum gravity to reconcile these two timescales.

Comment: @Andrew “*matter crossing the event horizon of a solar mass black hole will hit the singularity in order microseconds, while the timescale to evaporate is much larger than the current age of the Universe*” - Your objection is incorrect. In the coordinates of a free falling observer, the black hole evaporates before he crosses the horizon. And in the coordinates, in which a black hole takes longer than the age of the universe to evaporate, a falling matter never crosses the horizon. There is nothing to reconcile here for QG, because GR already reconciles these timescales with no contradiction..

Comment: @safesphere You're probably right that the numerical values I used are not directly comparable. I'm not convinced the point isn't still valid, though. Do you have a reference for this claim? *In the coordinates of a free falling observer, the black hole evaporates before he crosses the horizon.*

Comment: @Andrew your objection is correct. 
The phrase “the coordinates of a free falling observer” is ambiguous.  It doesn’t have a standard meaning, and if it did it would probably be something like Gullstrand Painleve coordinates, where your statement is true. Regardless of the coordinates used, there are worldlines that reach the singularity after a finite proper time. Such world lines will not escape if the black hole evaporates

Comment: @Dale Thanks. That is what I thought. Safesphere's comment made me wonder if there was something I hadn't understood about what BH evaporation looks like from the perspective of an infalling observer.

Comment: @Andrew There is a direct non-singular transformation between the proper time of a free falling observer and the Schwarzschild time. So you can easily calculate that the black hole evaporates in an instant on the clock of a free falling observer as he is reaching the horizon. This also is self evident without any calculations. From outside, the free falling observer is observed to be outside the horizon forever, meaning until the black hole evaporates. In GR, physics does not depend on the choice of coordinates. If we see him outside until the black hole is gone, he sees the same, only faster.

Comment: @safesphere I don't think we will resolve this in a comment thread. But I don't understand how to reconcile your statements with other results, such as the Penrose diagram for an evaporating black hole, where there are clearly infalling timelike geodesics that hit the singularity in finite proper time. I also don't understand it is possible to have "a direct non-singular transformation between the proper time of a free falling observer and the Schwarzschild time," given that the horizon is at infinite Schwarzschild time. If you do have a reference, I would enjoy reading it.

Comment: Here is the Penrose diagram: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Penrose-Diagram-for-black-hole-evaporation-The-singularity-is-depicted-by-green-curve_fig1_314115910

Comment: @Andrew The transformation I mentioned is for the proper time outside the horizon - obviously. The diagrams you refer to are incorrect. See this paper starting from Figure 1 and on: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.04879.pdf - “*Since a sketch like this inherently captures no more information than the assumptions put into creating it, it is difficult to learn anything from such a diagram.*” - The authors don’t claim their model is correct (and neither do I), but it proves the conventional diagrams wrong. We don’t have to resolve anything. Just give it a thought and don’t take any claims for granted.

Comment: @safesphere Thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 20):

Hawking radiation is not only in the form of photons. Fermions, scalars, other spin-1 particles, and even gravitons also contribute (for example, see https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370269311001559). So electrons and positrons are also emitted via Hawking radiation.

The origin of photons emitted during Hawking radiation is not an annihilation process between particles and anti-particles. Rather, the existence of the horizon changes the structure of the vacuum state experienced by an observer far away from the black hole (relative to what the vacuum would look like without a horizon), such that the observer sees a thermal bath of particles. The driving factor is the horizon, not interactions between particles. Exactly how this happens is difficult to explain without math.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134409/discussion-on-answer-by-andrew-how-can-black-holes-evaporate-into-photons-if-the).

Answer (score 6):

> how can the inside matter, composed of normal matter (so no anti-matter), be transformed into photons only?

Firstly, I need to make some disclaimers. We don't have a fully-working quantum gravity (QG) theory, so we don't know *exactly* what happens to matter when it reaches the core of a black hole. And we can't be *certain* that Hawking radiation is real without a proper QG theory: Hawking's calculations involve a semi-classical approximation that "bolts on" quantum corrections to the purely classical GR equations, and we need QG to justify that procedure.

However, what goes on inside a black hole isn't actually relevant to the rest of the universe. As I mentioned in a comment, the matter and energy inside the event horizon (EH) cannot affect the outside universe in any way. All events on or inside the EH are in the future light-cone of the observer, and of course events must be in the past light-cone to have an effect on the present.

As I said [here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/32677/16685), the gravitational field of a black hole is sometimes described as a ["fossil field"](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/BlackHoles/black_gravity.html). All matter & energy falling into the black hole modifies the spacetime curvature as it approaches the event horizon. And once it crosses the event horizon it can no longer change the spacetime curvature outside the horizon, so those curvature changes are preserved (until something else comes along to add its own curvature changes).

The same reasoning applies to the electromagnetic charge of the infalling matter and its effect on the electromagnetic field in the vicinity of the BH. It does *not* apply to the strong or weak nuclear "charges" because those interactions have finite range; only gravitation and electromagnetism are preserved due to their infinite range. This gives rise to the [no-hair theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-hair_theorem):

> The no-hair theorem states that all black hole solutions of the Einstein–Maxwell equations of gravitation and electromagnetism in general relativity can be completely characterized by only three externally observable classical parameters: mass, electric charge, and angular momentum. — Misner, Charles W.; Thorne, Kip S.; Wheeler, John Archibald (1973). *Gravitation*

> The result was quickly generalized to the cases of charged or spinning black holes. There is still no rigorous mathematical proof of a general no-hair theorem, and mathematicians refer to it as the no-hair conjecture.

So when particles fall towards a BH they "pump" energy into the spacetime curvature and EM field of the BH. We don't know or care what happens to those particles once they cross the EH because in our frame that's *always* in the future.

It's not easy to get an intuitive picture of what happens in and around a BH. Our intuitions aren't very good at dealing with curved spacetime. ;) But here's an analogous situation in flat spacetime that may be helpful.

Imagine we set off an H-bomb at location X at noon on Tuesday. If we try to measure the energy of the blast on the previous day, we won't measure anything, no matter how close we get to X, how big the bomb is, or how sensitive our instruments are. The blast energy simply doesn't travel backwards in time.

Similarly, energy from events inside the EH would have to travel backwards in time to affect events outside the EH.

I should mention that the EH is observer-dependent. The "official" EH at the Schwarzschild radius is the horizon of the [Schwarzschild observer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/552874/123208). That observer is the limiting case of an observer free-falling towards the BH with zero velocity, so they're at an infinite distance. The horizon for any observer free-falling towards a BH is always below them, until they hit the singularity. This relativity of horizon location means that different observers will measure different numbers of particles in the vicinity of the BH, and is ultimately what gives rise to Hawking radiation, as John Rennie explains [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/252236/123208). The mathematics used to perform the Hawking radiation calculations involves the [Bogoliubov transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogoliubov_transformation), which is a bit above my paygrade. ;)

In summary, the Hawking radiation is produced from the energy stored in the gravitational & electromagnetic field around the BH, and the types of particles that originally caused those stresses and strains in those fields is irrelevant.

Now, according to the [Bekenstein bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bekenstein_bound), the entropy of a BH is proportional to the surface area of the EH. So the information regarding the particles that formed the BH isn't exactly lost, but it's not exactly accessible either. As far as I know, Hawking radiation is supposed to be perfectly thermal, so we can't decode that information from the Hawking radiation.

---

BTW, you may enjoy playing with the [Hawking radiation calculator](https://www.vttoth.com/CMS/physics-notes/311-hawking-radiation-calculator). It makes a few approximations, but it's generally pretty good.

Comment: "the matter and energy inside the event horizon (EH) cannot affect the outside universe in any way."  What is it that produces the gravitational field around the black hole (which seems to affect the outside universe)?

Comment: @robjohn Ghosts. ;) The spacetime curvature outside the EH was produced by matter before it crossed the EH. In the frame of a distant observer, it takes infinite time for anything to reach the horizon. So for such observers the black hole is still in the process of forming. Bear in mind that the Schwarzschild solution (which is a vacuum solution) is only an approximate model to a real astrophysical black hole, and [real black holes tend to have a lot of spin](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/20292/16685), which makes things more complicated.

Comment: "We don't know or care what happens to those particles once they cross the EH because in our frame that's always in the future." Imagine though you fall in. The fall to the center takes little proper time (about the Schwarzschild radius divided by c). Before reaching the center, the hole could be evaporated. There will be an empty space again and you will be gone, while a faraway observer sees it all happening over a large time. Will you reappear again in the future? I mean, the particles you are made of and that fall in?

Comment: @Felicia I don't think so, because almost all Hawking radiation must be photons, only a *tiny* fraction of the BH energy gets emitted as particles with non-zero mass. Electrons & positrons don't get produced much until the mass drops below ~4E-17 solar masses.

Comment: If the location of the EH is observer-dependent, does it truly prevent infomation escaping? I could imagine a scenario where an infalling observer who is still outside the classical EH observes an event inside it - because said event is outside of where they observe the EH to be - and then re-transmits information about that event to the outside world.

Comment: @Skyler No. The EH of the distant observer determines the information limit for that observer. You can't get around that by having an intermediate observer acting as a relay.

Comment: It is likely that matter just  inside the event horizon doesn't affect spacetime curvature outside because accretion discs don't seem to have any anomalous distortion close to the event horizon

Comment: @Dave The inner edge of an accretion disk is some distance from the event horizon. For a Schwarzschild BH, the [ISCO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Innermost_stable_circular_orbit) radius is $3r_s$, but it can get closer for a Kerr BH. However, as I said above, stuff inside the EH *cannot* affect the outside universe because effects cannot propagate backwards in time.

Answer (score 5):

Black-holes are peculiar but nevertheless bona-fide quantum states of a given quantum field theory and therefore are expected to respect conservation laws: charge conservation, in particular. In a Einstein-Maxwell theory, if you build a black hole by throwing in only charged particles, it would have to radiate this charge away. A variation of this reasoning was used to come up with the "weak gravity conjecture", which roughly states that gravity is the weakest force. More precisely, it states that in a physical theory with charged particles coupled to gravity, you need to a have at least one particle with "more charge than mass" (in suitable units), for otherwise charged black-holes would be able to radiate all the charge away before fully evaporating.

Other symmetries of the standard model like Baryon number, Lepton number (which relate to matter/anti-matter asymmetry) are believed to be only approximate. But in grand unified theories, B-L (baryon minus lepton number) is usually taken to be conserved: this would constitute a global symmetry. And indeed, in quantum gravity, it is also believed that no global symmetry should exist, by similar sort of black-hole evaporation arguments. A rigorous demonstration of this has been given in certain space-times with boundary conditions such that quantum gravity is tractable in there (with negative cosmological constant), see [Harlow-Ooguri](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.05338). Quantum gravitational effects should therefore arise to break the B-L global symmetry at the Planck scale (or before).

Comment: Classical black holes obey charge conservation, though, without the need to invoke quantum mechanics at all.  The no-hair theorem has charge right there as one of the valid bulk parameters.  That's very different from things like baryon number, which would involve distinguishing a black hole that formed from stellar collapse from one that formed due to geons or some sort of exotic collapse of radiation or whatever.

Comment: A hole is formed out of matter. All this matter is gone after the evaporation. On the horizon, virtual particles turn real. Particle-antiparticle pairs (matter as well as gauge particles) radiate away and their negative energy parts fall to the inside. Can The positron negative energy states can annihilate all electrons, their mass as well as their charge. But what happens to negative energy electron states? Can they annihilate up-quarks (+2/3), or maybe two positrons (+2) annihilating three ups (also +2)?

Comment: @Felicia if you read the answers and links, baryon number, lepton number  are not conserved quantities within the horizon, at the present  understanding of the theories.

Answer (score 1):

### The extreme conditions inside break baryon conservation

In general relativity (GR), a black hole [forgets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-hair_theorem) everything except mass, spin, and charge. No matter, energy, or information that enters can leave, and the black hole will last forever.

Quantum mechanics (QM) does not [like it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_information_paradox) when information just disappears. And physics in general is time-reversible, even falling into a black hole.

This leaves us with the following situation:

1. GR says it is impossible for *any event* inside a black hole to affect any event outside. It is very accurate so long as the holes are much heavier than [the Planck mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_units) of 22 ug.
2. QM says that the hole will evaporate and that information escape is possible, somehow.

GR is *very accurate, but wrong*. It's accurate: it's impossible to deduce the baryon number or any other information about the inside of the hole (besides mass, spin and charge). But it's wrong: *in principle* this information is (likely) encoded by the escaping Hawking radiation.

Much like burning a book. The information is *in theory* encoded in the precise molecular state of the combustion products. But it is impossible to unscramble it.

A black-hole's inside is (probably) far, far move violent than any bonfire. GR predicts a "firewall" to form at the [*inner* horizon](https://jila.colorado.edu/%7Eajsh/insidebh/realistic.html) which destroys everything that enters the hole. Such a "firewall" also resolves some annoying details about the information paradox.

Baryon number is no longer conserved at these unfathomably high energies. The hot early universe produced more matter than antimatter. Similarly, a black hole destroys baryons and re-emit their energy as light and gravitons. The hole will emit matter and antimatter when it gets extremely small, but this is a tiny fraction of the total mass put in.

Answer (score 0):

A black hole has no net electric charge and the photon has none either So charge is conserved and there is no problem