# If a black hole doesn't have all its mass at a singularity and the mass is not uniformly distributed and rotating, would it emit gravitational waves?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, gravitational-waves

Would a black hole with a rotating  quadrupole moment in its mass distribution generate gravitational waves?

Comment: If I had water that wasn’t wet could I wash myself with it?

Comment: As I said [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/696441/123208), the matter and energy inside the event horizon cannot affect the outside universe in any way.

Comment: @PM2Ring  What about frame dragging?  http://ion.uwinnipeg.ca/~vincent/4500.6-001/Cosmology/Rotating_Black_Hole.htm   In the ergosphere the rotating Black Hole drags space around with it (called frame dragging) in such a way that all objects inside the ergosphere must rotate with the Black Hole.

Comment: @foolishmuse All of the properties of the BH are determined by what the matter & energy were doing before they crossed the EH. That applies to the angular momentum and the electric charge, as well as the gravity. That's why we call it a fossil field. Also see https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/3204/123208

Comment: @PM2Ring you are basically saying that all the warping of spacetime, i.e. the gravity of a black hole was determined at the moment the star collapsed past the event horizon.  And if the matter inside the black hole some how disappeared, then the black hole would continue to exist.  This is rather a new concept to me.

Comment: @foolishmuse I'm just saying that events in your future light cone cannot affect your present. Events inside the EH are in the future light cone of any observer outside the EH. 
Furthermore, the singularity of a BH is not in the past light cone of *any* observer, even those inside the EH.