If information can't move outwards the singularity then how does the event horizon "know" it has to expand simultaneously along the whole surface?
I have read this question:

When matter is added, carefully and radially to make sure it does not add angular momentum, the horizon radius increases proportionately to the amount of mass added (but see below you may also be adding 'kinetic and potential energy' in, so it must be accounted as part of the toal mass, or energy, added). Simple from the equation, thehorizon grows.

How do Black Hole event horizons grow?
What exactly makes a black hole STAY a black hole?
And this:
How can black hole increase its mass?
How can anything ever fall into a black hole as seen from an outside observer?
Now if all the mass-energy is stored in the singularity, and the black hole is just empty vacuum, then if it acquires new mass-energy, then it has to be "stored" in the singularity, and how does this information "travel" to the outermost region, and adjust the event horizon?
If my humble understanding is correct:

new mass-energy enters the black hole (black hole swallows particles etc.)

this mass-energy has to "travel" to the singularity where it is "stored"

information about the fact that the black hole's energy content has increased needs to travel from the singularity to the whole surface of the event horizon

the event horizon is not an object, but a boundary, and the whole boundary of this event horizon needs to adjust simultaneously


Now naively thinking this could happen two ways:
Version A:
As a new particle enters the black hole, information about this propagates through the whole surface of the event horizon at the speed of light. Considering that certain black holes can be ginormous, this process could take a while.
Version B:
As the new particle enters the black hole, it needs to reach the singularity first, since black holes are just empty vacuum of space, the singularity must contain all the mass-energy. Consecutively, information needs to travel from the singularity to the whole surface of the event horizon simultaneously to give it "instruction" to expand adequately to the mass-energy increase.
In my understanding Version A is possible but this process could take time as some black holes are giants so it cannot be simultaneous throughout the surface. Now Version B is to say the least doubtful, because nothing can travel outwards from/leave the singularity.
Question:

If information can't move outwards the singularity then how does the event horizon "know" it has to expand simultaneously along the whole surface?


I suspect that you're over-thinking this.The event horizon isn't a thing, it's just a location. Also, a singularity cannot affect anything outside of itself because the singularity is always in the future light-cone of any observer, including observers within the event horizon.

As I said here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/696441/123208 All matter & energy falling into the black hole modifies the spacetime curvature as it approaches the event horizon. And once it crosses the event horizon it can no longer change the spacetime curvature outside the horizon

@PM2Ring If a piece of matter just inside the event horizon moves by 1 meter, how exactly does the spacetime curvature values inside the horizon re-adjust themselves, such that all $g_{\mu\nu}$ outside the event horizon remains absolutely unchanged no matter how this object is moving inside the event horizon?

@James Comments aren't the right place to ask questions. But briefly, events inside the event horizon are in the future of events outside the horizon, and future events don't affect past events.

@PM2Ring thank you, I'd rather not burden the site with additional small questions. If I understood you right, the $g_{\mu\nu}$ both outside and inside the event horizon must obey $R_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}R = T_{\mu\nu}$ at any
spacetime slice, so supposing this object moves by 1 meter, then this $T_{\mu\nu}$ change will be propagated as $g_{\mu\nu}$ waves spreading outward, but any ripples due to this is somehow completely damped inside the event horizon, such that no $g_{\mu\nu}$ ripples can escape the event horizon ever?

@James We have a chat room for discussions: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar

“if all the mass-energy is stored in the singularity” - It is not. As observed from outside, all mass-energy is stored on the outer surface of the horizon forever. When a falling object approaches, the horizon (with all the matter already on it) expands out and meets the object at the larger radius. Also the horizon does not expand simultaneously everywhere, but quite the opposite actually. In this video the falling object is a small black hole, but the rest is what you are asking about: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Y1M-AbWIlVQ

@safesphere thank you so basically, the new matter infalling meets the expanding horizon, and this expansion spreads throughout from the point of entry? Please upvote if you like it.

@James I think you are correct, please upvote if you like it.

@ÁrpádSzendrei Yes, you got it right. The reason why the horizon expands toward the approaching object is simple. The horizon is simply where the Weyl (metric) curvature is maximal. A falling object has mass and also curves spacetime. On approach, this curvature adds up to the curvature near the horizon thus increasing the curvature between the object and the horizon. Due to this increase, the maximal curvature now happens sooner, at the radius larger than the previous radius of the horizon. And since the horizon simply is the location of the maximal curvature, it expands.

@safesphere this is a pretty good explanation, I think it should be an answer. Do you know if there is such thing as infinite curvature or is that just at the singularity?

@ÁrpádSzendrei I was referring to the metric curvature (the gravitational time dilation and space contraction). It is asymptotically infinite at the horizon in the coordinates of an external observer (e.g. time stops and length shrinks to zero). The curvature that is infinite only at the singularity is of a different type (scalar).

@ÁrpádSzendrei “the event horizon exists, but the singularity does not yet?” - A black hole turns the direction of time toward itself. This is why objects that move forward in time appear falling to the black hole. At the horizon the turn becomes 90 degrees, so it looks from outside as if time there stopped forever. Hence the horizon is a temporal tunnel beyond the infinite future of the universe.  Not only anything inside is in the future, but in the future relative to the very existence of the external universe. Once you cross to the inside, the external universe no longer exists for you.

@safesphere "Once you cross to the inside, the external universe no longer exists for you.", you mean it exist in your past?

@ÁrpádSzendrei Yes, exactly, it existed in your past, but doesn’t exist anymore in your present. It is gone. You cannot return to yesterday. This is why nothing from inside (future) can affect outside (past).

This is because the question that intrigued m was deleted, but it set me thinking about neutron stars. I found  this https://jnsfsl.sljol.info/articles/10.4038/jnsfsr.v13i2.8333 that gives a 24 mev work function for neutrons to escape from the  neutron star, which they do. I think the answer of why there is no fusion in a single star is due to the conservation laws and the quantum numbers of the possible decays and interactions, but it is not my area of research.


If information can't move outwards the singularity then how does the event horizon "know" it has to expand simultaneously along the whole surface?

The horizon doesn’t expand simultaneously along the whole surface. Meaning that the horizon does not typically remain spherical as it expands. It will bulge outwards towards infalling matter. It does so before the matter reaches the horizon.
Remember that the spherical symmetry of the Schwarzschild spacetime is a simplifying assumption made in order to make the math easier. When your spacetime of interest violates this symmetry then the resulting rules from the Schwarzschild geometry no longer apply.

information about the fact that the black hole's energy content has increased needs to travel from the singularity to the whole surface of the event horizon

The singularity is not a position in space, it is a moment in time. It lies to the future of the event horizon for a non-evaporating black hole. The event horizon is not caused by the singularity, and changes to the event horizon happen before the singularity.

Thank you so much!

"The singularity is not a position in space, it is a moment in time." Why is that everything else in the universe has 3 space coordinates and 1 time coordinate,, while singularities have the unique property of only having a time coordinate?

Pretty good answer. Can you please tell me "The singularity is not a position in space, it is a moment in time. It lies to the future of the event horizon", does this mean that the event horizon exists, but the singularity does not yet? Is this correct? Since the singularity is in the future of the event horizon, the event horizon (which we can observe from outside) can exist without the singularity (which will exist in the future of the event horizon)? Maybe I should ask another question?

Yes, the event horizon can exist without a singularity. In black hole collapse spacetimes the horizon forms first

@ÁrpádSzendrei Dale is correct plus there is a subtle difference between the event horizon (EH) and apparent horizon (AH). The horizon we can observe from outside is AH. It does not guarantee the future singularity. EH does guarantee the future singularity, but cannot be observed. If this wasn’t confusing enough already ;)

@safesphere thank you but why can the EH not be observed?

@ÁrpádSzendrei In simple terms, AH is from where light cannot escape now. So we can test and detect AH right now. In contrast, EH is from where light cannot escape ever, including the distant future. We don’t know right now what happens in the distant future. If nothing, then EH is there. But what if some foreign black hole flies by and grossly disturbs things around or perhaps something evaporates and  allows light to escape in the future? Then no EH ever existed. We cannot observe EH, because its existence and location today depends on what happens in the future.

@safesphere thank you please look at my question if you like it please upvote: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/829287/is-it-possible-to-start-a-nuclear-fission-chain-reaction-in-a-neutron-star

@safesphere here are two new questions, please upvote them if you like them: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/829579/how-exactly-do-neutron-star-mergers-create-heavy-elements
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/829577/why-is-it-that-for-light-elements-roughly-up-to-iron-fe-splitting-atoms-actu
