Do neutron stars fuse elements?
I have read these questions:

In reality, they fuse the hydrogen nuclei (the cores of the atom) together into helium nuclei.

https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/genesismission/gm2/mission/pdf/NeutronStars.pdf
Since the neutron star is the densest object we know, it should have enough gravity to fuse the neutrons (made up of quarks), and create the heavier elements.
Question:

Do neutron stars fuse elements?


As ProfRob says in https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/105475/123208 beta decay is heavily suppressed in a neutron star. But that mechanism is disrupted when neutron stars collide.

Please do not totally change the question after it has been answered. It appears you edited it as I answered the original. Your edit is a valid question but has a quite different answer.

I must have tried commenting during your edit  and I wrote this comment in a previous question of yours :your question set me thinking about neutron stars. I found this https://jnsfsl.sljol.info/articles/10.4038/jnsfsr.v13i2.8333 that gives a 24 mev work function for neutrons to escape from the neutron star, which they do. I think the answer of why there is no fusion in a single star is due to the conservation laws and the quantum numbers of the possible decays and interactions, but it is not my area of research.

@ProfRob can you please add something to your answer about the mergers? Or how can I repost this as a new question?

@ÁrpádSzendrei by posting a new question.

@annav thank you so much, based on your comments, and others I created 2 new questions, please upvote if you like them: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/829579/how-exactly-do-neutron-star-mergers-create-heavy-elements
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/829577/why-is-it-that-for-light-elements-roughly-up-to-iron-fe-splitting-atoms-actu

@ProfRob please see the new question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/829579/how-exactly-do-neutron-star-mergers-create-heavy-elements

I think your question is asking why, at the ultrahigh densities of a neutron star interior, don't the constituent neutrons (and a small fraction of protons and electrons) fuse into an enormous nucleus?
Actually, something like that does happen in the outer, lower density regions of a neutron star. The presence of an ultra-relativistic gas of degenerate electrons inhibits beta decay, and allows the formation of very large, neutron-rich nuclei, with atomic masses of several hundred. Larger nuclei become unstable to beta decay and/or fission.
At slightly higher densities, the equilibrium structures can become long chains and sheets, held together by the strong nuclear force, known as "nuclear pasta". The fission of the pasta is again suppressed by a "sauce" of degenerate electrons, but the increasingly dense fluid of surrounding free neutrons eventually pulls the nucleons out and dissolves these structures at higher densities.
However, if you increase the bulk density still further - towards the density of atomic nuclei - the configuration with the lowest energy density is for the majority of the nucleons to be free neutrons, with a few percent of free protons and electrons. Large nuclei cannot be built because the surrounding sea of nucleons can easily cause fission and dissolution of any structure.

Thank you so much!

@PM2Ring I have a new question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/829579/how-exactly-do-neutron-star-mergers-create-heavy-elements
