Why is it that for light elements, roughly up to iron ($\rm Fe$), splitting nuclei actually costs energy, rather than energy being released?
I have read this question:

For light elements, roughly up to iron ($\mathrm{Fe}$), splitting atoms actually costs energy, rather than energy being released.

How much energy is released from the splitting of a single hydrogen atom?
Question:

Why is it that for light elements, roughly up to iron ($\mathrm{Fe}$), splitting atoms actually costs energy, rather than energy being released?


Check the semi-empirical mass formula.

It's got to do with how much energy is stored in the nuclear bonds between protons and neutrons; for lighter atoms, energy is released during fusion and absorbed during fission, and for heavier atoms, it's the reverse. That's about as far as my knowledge extends; see agaminon's link.

See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/457686/why-do-fusion-and-fission-both-release-energy

The relationship between the energy required to split the nucleus (the "binding energy") per nucleon and the mass number forms a characteristic curve for the elements.
For light elements (up to iron), as nucleons are added, the binding energy per nucleon increases, reflecting the dominance of the strong nuclear force over the Coulomb repulsion. Thus, fusing light elements (like hydrogen and helium) releases energy, while splitting them costs energy. As you approach iron (mass number $\approx 56$), the binding energy per nucleon reaches its maximum (resulting in a very stable nucleus). Beyond iron, adding more nucleons leads to a net decrease in the binding energy per nucleon. Consequently, splitting these heavier nuclei releases energy due to the formation of more stable products with higher binding energies per nucleon.
Here's a plot of the binding energy per nucleon as a function of the mass number I borrowed from HyperPhysics.


You gave a reason why the binding energy per nucleon increases for lower mass number, but you did not explain why it decreases above iron.

@freecharly that isn't the question here and that question has been answered many times on Physics SE.
